# Using bash shell on RHEL 7 - why does find find more files when I don't use -exec?

Tags: unix, gnu-findutils, find-util

I'm looking for all setuid/setgid files.
When I don't use `-exec`, it works as expected:

```
# find /usr/bin -type f -perm -4000 -o -perm -2000 
/usr/bin/wall
/usr/bin/ksu
/usr/bin/chage
/usr/bin/chfn
/usr/bin/chsh
/usr/bin/fusermount
/usr/bin/passwd
/usr/bin/write
/usr/bin/su
/usr/bin/umount
/usr/bin/gpasswd
/usr/bin/newgrp
/usr/bin/mount
/usr/bin/pkexec
/usr/bin/crontab
/usr/bin/cgclassify
/usr/bin/cgexec
/usr/bin/ssh-agent
/usr/bin/Xorg
/usr/bin/at
/usr/bin/sudo
/usr/bin/locate
/usr/bin/staprun
```

When I use `-exec`, I only get a subset of the results back:

```
# find /usr/bin -type f -perm -4000 -o -perm -2000 -exec ls -l {} \;
-r-xr-sr-x. 1 root tty 15344 Jan 27  2014 /usr/bin/wall
-rwxr-sr-x. 1 root tty 19536 Aug 21  2015 /usr/bin/write
-rwxr-sr-x. 1 root cgred 15624 Sep 21  2014 /usr/bin/cgclassify
-rwxr-sr-x. 1 root cgred 15584 Sep 21  2014 /usr/bin/cgexec
---x--s--x. 1 root nobody 306304 Sep 24  2015 /usr/bin/ssh-agent
-rwx--s--x. 1 root slocate 40504 Jan 26  2014 /usr/bin/locate
```

Why?

Comment: You'd have the exact same behavior with an explicit `-print` on the end; it's nothing special about `-exec`.

Comment: By the way, `find` is not in any respect a part of `bash`. You could start `find` from Python or C without bash even installed on the system, and it would behave **precisely** the same way.

Comment: ...as another aside, consider `-exec ... +` rather than `exec ... \;`, wherever possible -- the former (part of the POSIX standard since 2006) passes as many arguments to each invocation as possible, thus minimizing the number of external commands run and performance overhead of same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're only using `-exec` on the right-hand side of the `-o`. Thus, it's being parsed like this:

```
# What's actually happening
find /usr/bin '(' -type f -perm -4000 ')' -o '(' -perm -2000 -exec ls -l {} \; ')'
```

Obviously, that's not what you want.

---

To make it apply to both sides of the conditional, add some parens for grouping:

```
# What you want to happen
find /usr/bin -type f '(' -perm -4000 -o -perm -2000 ')' -exec ls -l {} +
```

---

The reason is that if you don't specify an explicit action, `find` *assumes* a `-print` as the default action. When you add an action yourself it turns off that default, so only the items for which you explicitly specify an action get one.

That is to say:

```
# These commands are all equivalent:
find /usr/bin -type f -perm -4000 -o -perm -2000
find /usr/bin '(' -type f -perm -4000 -o -perm -2000 ')' -print
find /usr/bin '(' '(' -type f -perm -4000 ')' -o '(' -perm -2000 ')' ')' -print
```

Note that last one, which exposes a caveat in the default behavior: You probably wanted the `-type f` to apply to both sides of the `-o`, but without explicit grouping it gets put on the left, just as an explicit `-exec` or `print` gets put on the right.

Moral of this story: When using `-o` in find, be explicit about your grouping unless you're very certain that the default behavior is what you want.